# strange for loop syntax in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, syntax

I am reading `counting sort` algorithm on [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/). I have understood the algorithm but I am having a problem in the following `for loop` syntax.

```
for(int i=0; arr[i]; i++) {
 ++count[arr[i]];
 }
```

Here, `arr[]` is a `char` array and `count[]` is an `integer` array.

I have tried with the following code but it doesn't do anything:-

```
 for(int i =0; "c";i++){
    cout<<i;
}
```

Please help me to understand this kind of `for loop`.

Comment: Your cpp shell link is broken, it does not show any related code. Please demonstrate therefor your "it is not working" again. (Downvote not by me.)

Comment: I apologize for that. I thought I should just share the platform. I just see that we can share the code also.

Comment: OK, I can see the code now. And I can guess what is wrong with it. But please tell us what you mean by "does not work".

Comment: Hint, double check your statement "I have tried exactly the same syntax." because I see obvious differences...

Comment: By the way, even though your link now shows relevant code, it would be more appreciated if you would provide all information for your question (also) directly here. Try to make a [mcve] and show it directly here. Don't to describe the difference between expected and current result.

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually I misunderstood the implementation of `for` loop in the program given by geeks for geeks. I thought there is just a single character `a[i]` and the loop is working according to that so I put just one character in `cpp shell` implementation.

Comment: Yes, I thought so.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will definately follow these rules in next question .Thankyou for sharing

Comment: Consider starting right now. You could get to positive score... Keep in mind that this question is almost not understandable, if only looking at the info provided right here. You need the difference between the two codes to understand your actual problem. In this shape it will not impress people. But with the difference it could find some fans.

Comment: @Yunnosch is now my question make sense?

Comment: I can't align the "does not do anything" with the endless output I saw on the now deleted link... But it does make a sensible question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr[i]` evaluates to a character. If it is a null character then loop will terminate. You can think of it as

```
for(int i=0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++) {}
```

In C++ any value other than `0` evaluates to `true`. `'\0'` is encoded as `0` and therefore `arr[i]` will evaluate to `false` when it's value becomes `'\0'`.

n4659-§ 5.3/3:

> [...] null character (respectively, null wide character), whose value is `0` [...]

Comment: is it similar to `arr[i]  != '\0'`?

Comment: Yes, the statement will return 'True' or 'False'. So, `arr[i]` or `arr[i] != '\0'` is similar.